# Как предпочтительнее подключать модули к компонентам php

Tags: php

Я делаю пет проект и столкнулся с проблемой подключением глобальных для моего проекта модулей(header, footer, nav, config) в мои компоненты. К примеру как в страницу категорий, постов подключать эти файлы не относительным путём. У меня был вариант создать файл со всеми путями к глобальным модулями и подключать его абсолютным путём вообще ко всем компонентам и оттуда уже вытаскивать эти пути. Также был вариант добавить все пути к модулям в массив Globals, однако внутри компонентов я пару ключ значение не вижу и поэтому не знаю как быть. Какой способ де-факто здесь правильный? Ведь структура разрастается и подключать все относительным путём не очень удобно.

Comment: правильней взять какой нить шаблонизатор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы можете сделать себе так называемые alias-ы(сокращения, это общее понятие, не только в вебе), и работать с ними

в фреймворках эта фича уже реализирована([прим с yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases)), в самописце делайте как хотите.

В итоге, получится что-то типа:

```php
# 1 конфигурация
$config = [
....
....
aliases => [
    'backend' => 'путь к директории backend',
    'common' => 'путь к директории common'
]
];

# 2 использование во view
$path = $application->getAlias('backend').'/путь к модулю';
$this->render($path,$data);
```

---

upd.

А зачем вы подключаете файлы напрямую то?

Мне кажется лучше было бы сделать пару виджетов(которые офк знают пути), и вызывать их

---

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду через нэймспейсы делать? Я просто встраиваю php код в html и не особо понимаю что такое виджеты в этом контексте

Comment: виджет, это некий класс, который берёт некие данные, и отрисовывает их в html. Например, часто в магазинах вы можете увидеть виджет "последние просмотренные товары". По факту, туда кидают массив, а класс рисует html.